# vue2-editor not working for nuxt js. reference error: document is not defined

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I tried to use vue2-editor. so when i tried with basic process which is in the documentation

```
import { VueEditor } from "vue2-editor";
   export default {
     components: {
        VueEditor
     },

<template>
   <div id="app">
      <vue-editor v-model="content"></vue-editor>
   </div>
</template>
```

it gives me reference error document is not defined...
so then i tried to use it as plugin...in plugin, i defined

```
import Vue from "vue";
import { VueEditor } from "vue2-editor";

Vue.use(VueEditor);
```

and in nuxt.config.js

```
plugins: [
       { src: '~/plugins/vueditor', mode: 'client'},
]
```

now it doesnt show any error but editor doesnt show up.

i have also tried with { src: '~/plugins/vueditor', mode: 'client', ssr: false},
anyone who can help me with this.?

Comment: You need to pass whole error message

Comment: The second form is correct and should work. Did you inspected with the Vue devtools why this is not showing up? How did you called it?

Comment: it says in console Unknown custom element: <vue-editor>... do i have to import the plugin into my component.? i have already registered the component in plugin as Vue.component('vue-editor', VueEditor)

Comment: If you want me to be notified, you have to @kissu me. Otherwise, this should be okay. Keep the `mode: client`, and double check the path and maybe put `@` instead of `~`.